# Finding the centralizer of each element of $Q_{4n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**Find the centralizer of each element of the dicyclic group of order $4n$.**

**My try**:

Consider the dicyclic group given by $Q_{4n}=\{\langle a, b\rangle : a^{2n}=b^4=1, ab=ba^{-1},a^2=b^2\}$.
The elements of $Q_{4n}$ are $\{a,a^2,a^3,\ldots, a^{2n}=1, ba,ba^2, \ldots, ba^{2n}=b\}$.

Now the center of $Q_{4n}$ is $Z(Q_{4n})=\{1,a^n\}$.

Centralizer of $a^i=C(a^i)=\{1, a,a^2,\ldots, a^{n-1}\}.$

I think that Centralizer of $ba^i=C(ba^i)=\{1, ba^i, ba^{i+n},a^n\}.$

I am stuck on $C(ba^i)$.
I can see that $\{1, ba^i, ba^{i+n},a^n\}\subseteq C(ba^i)$ but I don't understand how to find $C(ba^i)$.

Is there any way to find the centralizer apart from checking each element of $Q_{4n}$?

Can someone please help me to find $C(ba^i)$?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $ba^i$ conjugate $a$ to?

Comment: @DavidCraven; I dont understand what do you mean

Comment: What is $a^{ba^i}$?

Comment: @DavidCraven; what does that even mean, $a^{ba^i}$ , sorry i never seen this. You are raising $a$ to the power $ba^i$? how does it make sense?

Comment: $(ba^i)^{-1}\cdot a\cdot (ba^i)$. I guess you are doing a homework sheet, and are trying to compute centralizers before you have done conjugates. In that case, compute $(ba^i)\cdot a^j$ and compare it to $a^j\cdot (ba^i)$. Then you will know for which $j$, $a^j$ lies in the centralizer of $ba^i$.